# Fill dictionary with dynamic values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dynamic

I got a probem I am not able to solve for quiet some time and maybe someone of you can help me.

Because it is a more easy code and it's clear what it is good for, I would like to start wit the code:

```
#Create empty dictionary
lit_dict = {}
#List with different material names
mat_category_list = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'Default']
#Fill lit_dict with lists called e.g "lit_names_X" for every material 
for mat in mat_category_list:
    lit_dict['lit_name_%s'%mat.lower()] = [('Choose Manually','Choose Manually','Choose the value using the button below')]
```

So far the code is working fine. I get a dictionary (lit_dict) with a key called *lit_name_A* for every material A stored in the list mat_category_list. Furthermore, every key has the value *('Choose Manually','Choose Manually','Choose the value using the button below')*. That's exactly what I want. Every value has to be a tuple.

Now we are getting to the problem. I have a dictionary called *mat_properties_A* for every material A. These dictionaries look like that e.g.:

```
mat_properties_A= {'A.Geramy,2000':Material_Property(13700.0,0.38,reference='A.Geramy,2000',mat='Bone')
```

I now want a loop which adds for every material A the names of every key of the mat_properties_A dictionary as a tuple to my *lit_dict* to the right list *lit_name_A*

The loop should look like that:

```
for mat in mat_category_list:
    for lit in mat_properties_A.keys():
            lit_dict['lit_value_%s'%mat.lower()] += [tuple([lit]*3)]
```

My problem is now that the A in the second row above has to be dynamic that means it has to change with the *mat* loop. I tried to solve that probelm with a setattr() or so but it does not work.

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that problem?

**Edit1:**
To clearify more what I want to achieve:
I am working with Blender. There I have 2 Dropdown menus. One where I can choose the material I want (e.g. X) and then a second Dorpdown menu where then (based on the choosen material in the first drowpdon) I can choose the corresponding names of literature.

So for example:

---

Dropdown 1: "X"

---

Dropdown 2: Shows all Names stored in the list *lit_name_x*

---

Tha is why I need a *lit_name_x* for every material in the *mat_category_list*. The *mat_category_list* contains all materials which can be selected in Dropdown Menu 1. And because the user is able to create own materials, with own literature, the whole code has to be independent of the names of the materials.

I hope it is more clear what I want as a "Outcome"

Comment: Given that you've already demonstrated that you know how to use dictionaries, why don't you use another dictionary?

Comment: I think I don't understand your approach/tip completely. So I should create a dictionary with the mat_properties_A as keys and the names as values and then fuse the dicitonaries?

Comment: So you'd have `{'mat_properties_A': {'A.Germany,2000': Material_Property(..), ...}, ...}`.

Comment: Can you add the output you want? or what exactly you want?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : But I think that does not solve the problem. I need a list that looks like this one `lit_name_x = [('Adam, 2010', 'Adam, 2010', 'Adam, 2010), ('Bertram, 2001', 'Bertram, 2001', 'Bertram, 2001')]`

Comment: @SuJaY : I edited my original post to clearify that more

Comment: *"I need a lit_name_x for every material in the mat_category_list"* - then you should use a nested dictionary.

Comment: With the hint from @Hooting it worked and I got a nested dictionary which loosk like this `{'lit_value_materail': [('Choose Manually', 'Choose Manually', 'Choose the value using the button below'), ('Poppe et al,2002', 'Poppe et al,2002', 'Poppe et al,2002')]`

Answer (score -2):

```
for mat in mat_category_list:
    keys = eval("mat_properties_%s.keys()" % A)#here, A is the name from mat
    for lit in keys:
            lit_dict['lit_value_%s'%mat.lower()] += [tuple([lit]*3)]
```

Comment: `eval` is almost exactly *never* the right way of doing things.

Comment: Thansk for the hint @Hooting. I now got exactly what I wanted :)